# Removing multiple jquery DOM elements in array at once?

Tags: jquery

I have a bunch of DOM elements in a container.

```
  const arr = []      
  var domEL = template("templateName", json)
    .appendTo("#container");
  var domEL2 = template("templateName", json)
    .appendTo("#container");
  var domEL3 = template("templateName", json)
    .appendTo("#container");
  arr.push(domEL)
  arr.push(domEL2)
  arr.push(domEL3)
```

This doesn't work:

```
  $(arr).remove()
```

How do I make this work without using a loop?

Tried

```
  const arr = $()      
  var domEL = template("templateName", json)
    .appendTo("#container");
  var domEL2 = template("templateName", json)
    .appendTo("#container");
  var domEL3 = template("templateName", json)
    .appendTo("#container");
  arr.add(domEL)
  arr.add(domEL2)
  arr.add(domEL3)
```

This doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: What does `template("templateName", json)` return?

Comment: @Taplar it's a jquery element, with working `.appendTo("#container")`

Comment: Can you show us that logic.  If it returns a jQuery object containing Elements, or is a native Element, then the remove logic should work.

Comment: Better yet, make a [mcve]

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/aqpvL0yk/ removing an array of elements works as expected

Comment: @Taplar thanks for the fiddle, seems like the trick is to get the native element instead of keeping the jquery wrapper. If you remove the get(0) it stops working.

Comment: Because `get()` returns an array, so you'd have an array of arrays of elements.  The arrays are not in the dom.  Their inner elements are.

Comment: @Taplar yeah I get it, though I assumed jquery handled that. It does mean my original try is not supposed to work, you need the inner elements. You can post this as an answer if you want a check mark.

Comment: I'm good.  I didn't solve your logic.  I just showed you that it should work, :)